# failed to connect to 192.168.95.2 on port 80

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run my android app on real android device and i put the IPv4 address as URL , but i get an error that says failed to connect to 192.168.95.2 on port 80 , i tried all things in previous questions but didn't work out also checked my permissions and make sure that i added internet permission  :/
here is the code :

```
public class Constants {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.95.2/";
public static final String REGISTER_OPERATION = "register";
public static final String LOGIN_OPERATION = "login";
public static final String CHANGE_PASSWORD_OPERATION = "chgPass";

public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String FAILURE = "failure";
public static final String IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";

public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String UNIQUE_ID = "unique_id";

public static final String TAG = "Learn2Crack";
```

Comment: why *should* it work? You know that is local network ip?

Comment: Whose IP address is this? From your computer? Can you access this IP from a browser on the android device?

Comment: Does your app ask for internet permissions?

Comment: please demonstrate what you already facing, is your android device connected on same internet?